# Keycloak docker doesn't start because WildFly initial state transfer timed out for cache

Tags: docker, wildfly, keycloak

I'm using `jboss/keycloak:15.1.0` docker image for integration testing in the Gitlab CI. Single Keycloak service for a job with many jobs as a part of a single pipeline. Sometimes it fails to start (in less than 1/4 of cases). The issue was observable for `jboss/keycloak:15.0.2` as well.

The only startup arguments that I set are `KEYCLOAK_USER`, `KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD`, `KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL`, and `DB_VENDOR`. Which is equivalent to `docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin@email.com -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG -e DB_VENDOR=h2 jboss/keycloak:15.0.2`.

The first error in the chain is

```
11:03:41,856 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
```

Here are more error/warning logs

```
2021-12-16 11:03:42 
11:03:42,079 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2021-12-16 11:03:42 
11:03:42,078 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2021-12-16 11:03:42 
11:03:42,075 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: Keycloak 15.1.0 (WildFly Core 15.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 246739ms - Started 633 of 949 services (14 services failed or missing dependencies, 701 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2021-12-16 11:03:42 
11:03:42,066 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2021-12-16 11:03:42 
WFLYCTL0448: 3 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
2021-12-16 11:03:42 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:42 
11:03:42,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
2021-12-16 11:03:42 
11:03:42,003 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name : "keycloak-server.war")
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4"}}
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work" => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("store" => "none")
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("replicated-cache" => "work"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
11:03:41,989 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4"}}
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work" => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("memory" => "heap")
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("replicated-cache" => "work"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
11:03:41,989 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4"}}
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work" => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("component" => "transaction")
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("replicated-cache" => "work"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
11:03:41,989 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4"}}
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work" => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("component" => "state-transfer")
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("replicated-cache" => "work"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
11:03:41,988 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4"}}
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work" => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("component" => "partition-handling")
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("replicated-cache" => "work"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
11:03:41,988 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4"}}
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work" => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("component" => "locking")
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("replicated-cache" => "work"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
11:03:41,988 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4"}}
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work" => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("component" => "backups")
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("replicated-cache" => "work"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
11:03:41,987 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4"}}
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work" => "org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("replicated-cache" => "work")
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("cache-container" => "keycloak"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
11:03:41,986 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2021-12-16 11:03:41 

2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    ... 7 more
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.wildfly.clustering.service@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalService.start(FunctionalService.java:63)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.service.CacheServiceConfigurator.get(CacheServiceConfigurator.java:55)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.service.CacheServiceConfigurator.get(CacheServiceConfigurator.java:77)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.getCache(DefaultCacheContainer.java:92)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:510)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalGetCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:532)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:643)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:697)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.start(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:512)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.start(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:512)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.start(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:512)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:1011)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.infinispan@11.0.9.Final//org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.waitForInitialStateTransferToComplete(StateTransferManagerImpl.java:246)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.wildfly.clustering.service@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsyncServiceConfigurator$AsyncService.lambda$start$0(AsyncServiceConfigurator.java:117)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
    at org.wildfly.clustering.service@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalService.start(FunctionalService.java:66)
2021-12-16 11:03:41 
11:03:41,856 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache.keycloak.work: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Initial state transfer timed out for cache work on runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-54h6r4
2021-12-16 11:00:06 
11:00:06,819 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote] (ClusterTopologyRegistrar - 1) WFLYEJB0509: Clustered Jakarta Enterprise Beans in Node: runner-ajvcf6kf-project-136-concurrent-6x4j6c are bound to INADDR_ANY(0.0.0.0). Either use a non-wildcard server bind address or add client-mapping entries to the relevant socket-binding for the Remoting connector
```

[Here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/files/7728366/keycloak.txt) are full logs.

It looks like a bug in Keycloak or its dependencies. I assume that the underlying error is Wildfly not being able to start `Initial state transfer timed out for cache work`. It's not clear what causes the issue though.

It looks like the others face similar issues. E.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234156/infinispan-initial-state-transfer-timout) and [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/experiencing-infinispan-timeouts/4456). The suggested workarounds where to reconfigure Wildfly (e.g., to increase the timeout), yet I'm not sure if it's feasible for the Keycloak docker container.

[Here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/9195) is the corresponding Keycloak issue.

Any ideas (even workarounds) are welcome.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution? Please share it if so